# $z = \sum_{i = 1}^n x_i \otimes y_i$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, vector-spaces, tensor-products, tensors

Let $U$ and $V$ be $K$-vector spaces, with $\{u_i\}_{i \in I}$ base of $U$ and $\{v_j\}_{j \in J}$ base of $V$. If $z \in U \otimes V$, prove there exists $y_i \in V$ unique such that $z = \sum_{i \in I} u_i \otimes y_i$.

The same can be proved for $x_j \in J$ unique such that $z = \sum_{j \in J} x_j \otimes v_j$.

Lastly, prove there exists $x_1, \dots, x_n \in U$ and $y_i, \dots, y_n \in V$, linearly independent such that $z = \sum_{i = 1}^n x_i \otimes y_i$.

I guess the first and second are easy. I did

$$z = (\sum_{i \in I} a_iu_i) \otimes v = \sum_{i \in I} u_i \otimes a_iv$$

Then $y_i = a_iv$.
The same for the second question. I don’t know if this is correct.

The last I don’t know how to prove.

Answer (score 1):

Your proof for the first (and second) question *essentially* establishes existence (see my comment below), but not uniqueness. You need to establish that if we have
$$
\sum_{i} u_i \otimes y_i = \sum_{i} u_i \otimes y_i',
$$
then we have $y_i = y_i'$ for all $i \in I$. Equivalently, we are given that $\sum_{i}u_i \otimes (y_i - y_i') = 0$, and we want to deduce that $y_i - y_i' = 0$ for all $i \in I$.

As in my answer on your previous, I would recommend that you show that if $y_i - y_i' \neq 0$ for some $i$, then $\sum_{i}u_i \otimes (y_i - y_i') \neq 0$. Do this by constructing a suitable linear map and appealing to the universal definition of the tensor product

---

I find the last question to be very tricky. Things are a bit easier if we are given that either $U$ or $V$ is finite dimensional, but even this case is a bit tricky.

The easiest method I can think of is to exploit the canonical identification of $U \otimes V$ with $\operatorname{Hom}(U^*,V)$ (where $U^*$ denotes the dual of $U$).  Because $z \in U \otimes V$, we can write $z = \sum_{i \in I} p_i \otimes q_i$ for some $p_i,q_i$ and finite indexing set $I$. Let $U_0 \subset U$ denote the (finite dimensional!) subspace of $U$ spanned by $\{p_i : i \in I\}$. Let $\Phi: \operatorname{Hom}(U_0^*,V) \to U_0 \otimes V$ denote the canonical isomorphism defined such that
$$
\Phi(vf(\cdot)) = f \otimes v.
$$
Let $\phi = \Phi^{-1}(z)$. Note that the (finite rank) map $\phi:U_0^* \to V$ can be decomposed into a "rank-factorization" $\phi = \phi_2 \circ \phi_1$ where $r$ is the rank of $\phi$, $\phi_1:U_0^* \to \Bbb F^r$, and $\phi_2:\Bbb F^r \to W$.  If $u_j \in U,v_j \in V$ are defined such that
$$
\phi_1(f) = (f(x_1),\dots,f(x_r)), \quad \phi_2(c_1,\dots,c_r) = c_1 y_1 + \cdots + c_r y_r,
$$
then it follows that
$$
\phi(f) = \sum_{j=1}^r f(x_j) y_j, \quad
\Phi(\phi) = \sum_{j=1}^r x_j \otimes y_j.
$$

Comment: How does the approach to the first question even prove existence? The elements of $U\otimes V$ are not just the simple tensors $u\otimes v$. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Christoph the argument is technically incomplete: in full, we would extend the argument by linearity to say that
$$
z = \sum_{j \in J}\left(\sum_{i \in I} a_{ij}u_i\right) \otimes v_j = \sum_{i \in I} u_i \otimes \left(\sum_{j \in J} a_{ij} v_j\right)
$$